# Specific routing for a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this url:

```
http://localhost:3256/publicview/details?username=mvcpro4
```

which works and returns the view with data.

which i would like to be this url:

```
http://localhost:3256/publicview/details/mvcpro4
```

which doesnt work, when it gets the controller the ***username*** parameter is null.

How do i need to configure the publicview route, so it doesn't break the default routing.

I have these routes in place.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "publicview",
                "publicview/details",
                new { controller = "publicview", action = "details" }
            );

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty much just like you have already

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "publicview",
            "publicview/details/{userName}",
            new { controller = "publicview", action = "details", userName=UrlParamter.Optional }
        );
```

Make sure that you call the string parameter userName in your details action so it populates.

or you can just remove the above route and change the parameter to id in your details action so it uses the standard route

be careful of special characters in the url, or .net runtime will kick off and throw exceptions at you.

http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2011/04/18/use-of-special-characters-like-in-an-iis-url.aspx